# Proving or providing a counterexample to $Y$ being bounded complete

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $Y$ denote a random variable on $\{-1,0,1\}$ such that $P(Y=-1)=p, \ P(Y=0)=1/2$ and $P(Y=1)=1/2-p$. Here $p \leq 1/2$

My question: Is $Y$ bounded complete (where we think of the statistic $T$ as just the identity)?

Here bounded complete just be understand as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics).

My intuition tells me it is but I have trouble with applying the definition (taking an arbitrary bounded, measurable function $g$ where $E[g(Y)]=0$ for any $p$  and showing the $g(Y)=0$ a.s.)

Can anyone help me prove it or is there a counter example I am missing?

Comment: Take $g$ is the identity, and $p=1/4$.

Comment: The identity is not bounded.

Comment: Well by identity, I really mean the identity on -1,0,1. The values it takes on elsewhere is immaterial.